# Angular - Generate unique css id for each table cell

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on a project where I need a unique CSS id for each table cell. The format of table in something like this.

```
<tr *ngFor="let classroom of schoolReportData ; let i = index">
  <td id="{{ 'pieChartDiv'+(i+1) }}"></td>
  <td id="{{ 'pieChartDiv'+(i+1) }}"></td>
  <td id="{{ 'pieChartDiv'+(i+1) }}"></td>
  <td id="{{ 'pieChartDiv'+(i+1) }}"></td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to generate css `id` with the above method where I am incrementing the index variable with 1. This trick is not working and all the `td` getting the same `id`, although this method is generating a unique id for each row.

I really appreciate any help. I did a lot of tricks but nothing really works for me :(

Thank you!

Comment: what is output you are getting ?

Comment: what is the value of index at the output?

Comment: I'm getting the same id for all the `td`, but I want unique id for them.

Comment: Output of above code is `pieChartDiv1` for all the td of first row.

Comment: in your case you should get 4 `td` with the same `id` for each element in `schoolReportData`, if you need unique `id`, leave only one `td` inside `*ngFor`

Comment: try out answer as suggested that will generate unique id for td element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Try like this with column name + index of loop you can generate unique id.

```
<tr *ngFor="let classroom of schoolReportData ; let i = index">
  <td id="{{ classroom.field1 + '_'+ i }}"></td>
  <td id="{{ classroom.field2 + '_'+ i }}"></td>
  <td id="{{ classroom.field3 + '_'+ i }}"></td>
  <td id="{{ classroom.field4 + '_'+ i }}"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

try like as below

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4];


<tr *ngFor="let classroom of schoolReportData ; let i = index">
  <td *ngFor="let a of arr;" id="{{ 'pieChartDiv'+a }}"></td>
</tr>
```

because if you put `id="{{ 'pieChartDiv'+(i+1) }}"` then it should generate same id for all td element.

Comment: I can't apply a loop on td because I'm showing API response in the table. It becomes so difficult to get that data in the loop.

Comment: @Neeraj - if you can share more details like what is reponse or object structure i can help more on that

Comment: @PranayRana. I really thanks you for your help, but Dhaval Gohel's trick worked for me.

Comment: @Neeraj - welcome next time its better you provide more context so it will be hepful to give good solution

Comment: but this will give the same id for the cells of each tr .

Answer (score 0):

This way you can generate it.

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let classroom of schoolReportData">
  <td *ngFor="let a of [0,1,2,3,4,5]" id="{{ 'pieChartDiv'+a }}"></td> 
</tr>  
</table>
```